# Proof for the sampling variance of the Neyman Estimator

Tags: variance, sampling, proof

I'm going through Imbens and Rubin's [new book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Bf1tBwAAQBAJ&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=causal%20inference%20for%20statistics%20social%20and%20biomedical%20sciences%20an%20introduction&source=bl&ots=jcYGeg2SEB&sig=-0MuOLc-vvRGYphaDACUY3RLaOU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBGoVChMIseHY9ICGxgIVBpSICh3uFwAn#v=onepage&q=causal%20inference%20for%20statistics%20social%20and%20biomedical%20sciences%20an%20introduction&f=false) and I just for the life of me can't figure out 1 minor detail in their proof for the sampling variance of the Neyman estimator $\bar{Y}^{obs}_{t} - \bar{Y}^{obs}_{c}$.

The proof is [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=FYeSBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT117&ots=g1mQHpqEFR&dq=proof%20of%20the%20sampling%20variance%20of%20the%20neyman%20estimator&pg=PT132#v=onepage&q&f=false) - you don't have to go down but a few lines to get to where I'm stuck.

I just can't derive on my own why $Var(D_{i}) = \frac{N_{c}N_{t}}{N^2}$.

Could someone lay out how its derived? Basic question, but significant effort and online searching has proven fruitless.

Comment: I was able to find a more detailed and clear explanation online [here](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5d54a19a5a1edf0001ea677a/t/6092ac3aca335448423a1307/1620225083524/Tom_Leavitt_var_diff_means_estimator.pdf) This should help you.

Answer (score 2):

$N_t$ and $N_c$ are fixed by the design, with $N_t +N_c=N$.

Define
 $P_t = \dfrac{N_t}{N}$ and $P_c = \dfrac{N_c}{N} = 1-P_t$.

$W_i =1$ for treated observations, $=0$ for controls. The key fact is that the $W_i$ are independent and follow a Bernoulli distribution with index $P_t$.

The text gives the centered treatment indicators.
$$
D_i = W_i - \frac{N_t}{N} = W_i - P_t
$$

$P_t$ is non-random, so $D_i$ has the same variance as $W_i$, and

\begin{align}
var(D_i) & = P_t(1-P_t) \\
& = P_t\times P_c \\
& = \frac{N_t}{N} \times \frac{N_c}{N} \\
& = \frac{N_t N_c}{N^2} \\
\end{align}